# How to bring each word letter in array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach

I have a problem in my code and I have no idea how to fix it. I need to copy every letter of the user entered word to array, but there is an error "Index was outside the bounds of the array". I know that thir error means that I don't have correct size of the array, but I am using ReadLine and I can't enter static size. It can be changed due user entered text.

Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int c = 0;
            string text = Console.ReadLine();

            string[] str = new string[] { };



            foreach (char letter in text)
            {

                str[c] = Convert.ToString(letter);
                Console.WriteLine(str[c]);
                c++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Use a list instead of an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define length of `str`

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int c = 0;
    string text = Console.ReadLine();
    string[] str = new string[text.Length];//<-- NOTE THIS
    foreach (char letter in text)
    {
        str[c] = Convert.ToString(letter);
        Console.WriteLine(str[c]);
        c++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq to make this a one-liner:

```
using System.Linq;
// ...
// ...
var separateLettersAsList = text.ToList();
var separateLettersAsArray = text.ToArray();
```

Comment: I don't know how it works yet, but I'll try, thanks.